# How to determine if a service automatically restarts after a crash

Tags: linux

**Environment:** CentOS 8

For custom applications it is relatively straightforward to write an auto-restart script to restart an application if it crashes.

However many popular, widely used packages are designed to automatically restart on their own after a crash.

**Question:** How do I know which packages automatically restart after a crash?

I visited my `/etc/systemd/system` folder to look for evidence but I didn't find much.

The only reference in the `system` folder to packages I'm concerned about is a `redis.service.d` folder.

I'm looking for Postfix, Dovecot, Opendkim, Nginx, Redis & FirewallD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) service files.

Example :

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/srv/www/sites/rails_app/current/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid
RemainAfterExit=no
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
```

Check the last lines, this configuration will restart the app automatically on crash.

Check:
https://singlebrook.com/2017/10/23/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/
https://ma.ttias.be/auto-restart-crashed-service-systemd/